# How to compact a directory

Tags: filesystems, ext3

Every so often, some application runs wild and fills a directory with a huge amount of files. Once we fix the bug and clean up the files, the directory stays big (>50MB) even though there's only 20-30 files in it.

Is there some command that compacts a directory without having to recreate it?

Bonus points: does a huge empty directory affect access performance of that directory? I'm assuming it does, but maybe it's not worth bothering. It seems slower to do `ls` on such a directory.

Comment: I don't think there is such a thing (but I could of course be completely wrong). Maybe some filesystem-specific tools though - what FS are you using?

Comment: ext3, but I've seen that problem on most filesystems I've dealt with in the unix world. I don't think there is such a tool either, but I'd like to be proven wrong.

Comment: I tagged your question "ext3" since this question is very filesystem-specific. I don't know the answer for ext3 (I suspect you need to recreate the directory to get it to shrink) but have you tried to force an `fsck`? ext3's `fsck` has an "Optimizing directory" pass. I don't know what that does, but maybe it shrinks directories that are too big? Anyway, as a data point FWIW, xfs autoshrinks directories that have had files removed from them.

Comment: Have you by chance deleted open files?

Comment: Nope, files were closed at deletion time, and whatever process that might have kept them open has been restarted.

Comment: So xfs does fix that problem. Nice.

Comment: ufs on the BSDs and Mac HFS both shrink directories on the fly also.  I'm surprised to learn that ext3 doesn't.  ext4 doesn't seem to do it, either.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303008/how-to-defragment-a-directory-on-ext3

Answer (score 10):

You run `e2fsck -D` on the unmounted filesystem.

Comment: I was hoping for something less disruptive.

Comment: @MathieuLongtin, You also could move everything to a new directory, delete the old one, and rename the new one back.

Comment: I knew about that trick, but it can mess up processes using the directory as a current working directory.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly an answer, but I think it's worth mentioning here, that there was a patch to fix this inability to shrink the directory:

https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-ext4/msg71205.html

I hope it gets merged one day.

Comment: Good news if it gets merged!